# JUnit testing to get the bigger number of 2 values?

Tags: java, junit, assertions

I need some help figuring out how to get a JUnit test of the bigger number of 2 values.

I know how to do Junit testing of simple functions like adding, subtracting and etc but not finding a bigger value of the two.

This is what I have:

```
 public static int getMax(int x, int y){
        if(x >= y) {
            return x;
        }
        else {
            return y;
        }
    }
```

Im stuck on proving what I wrote.

Comment: You should think of test cases.. x=y, x<y, x>y, using negatives, using 0, using positives.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your getMax method returns x if it is equal or greater than y, otherwise it will return y. This is not a Unit or JUint test. If this is your method you are writing a unit test for, the unit test method should be something like:
@Test
public void testGetMax() ...

Answer (score 0):

When doing unit testing what you are doing is calling the function and comparing it's
result to what you expect testing this should be no different to what you have already done.

using junit 4

```
@Test public void mySimpleTestCase(){
    // assertEquals tells junit you want the two values to be equal
    // first parameter is your expected result second is the actual result
    assertEquals(2 , MyFunctions.getMax(1,2) );
}

@Test public void myComplexTestCase(){
    // by generating numbers randomly we can do a slightly 
    // different test each time we run it.
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt();
    int j = r.nextInt();
    if (i > j){
      assertEquals("looking for max of " +i + " : " + j, i , MyFunctions.getMax(i,j) );
    } else {
      assertEquals("looking for max of " +i + " : " + j, j , MyFunctions.getMax(i,j) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `complextTestCase` is wrong for when `i==j`. I would also recommend testing the other 2 general use cases if i>j and i==j as separate tests before going with a random number generator since if there is a error (like here) we might not notice for a while and then be confused when the test suddenly fails for no apparent reason.

Comment: if i == j then both i and j are max.

Answer (score 0):

From inspecting the code, there is only a single branch and therefore only two cases to cover:

```
@Test
public void firstNumberGreaterThanSecondIsReturned()
{
    assertEquals(1, NumericUtils.getMax(1, 0));
}
```

and:

```
@Test
public void secondNumberGreaterThanFirstIsReturned()
{
    assertEquals(1, NumericUtils.getMax(0, 1));
}
```

If you were writing this as TDD you might start with equal numbers or other boundary cases,
but unless there are further cases that you're not confident about then adding more tests isn't worth it.

Answer (score 0):

i would do:

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.TestWith;
import com.googlecode.zohhak.api.runners.ZohhakRunner;

@RunWith(ZohhakRunner)
class MyMaxTest {

  @TestWith({
     "1, 2, 2",
     "2, 1, 2",
     "1, 1, 1"
  })
  public void shouldReturnMaximum(int number1, int number1, int expected) {

    int result = MyClass.getMax(number1, number2);

    assertThat(result).isEqualTo(expected);
  }

}
```